# Jaxws notifications

Tags: jakarta-ee, wsdl, jax-ws, ws-notification

Could you please help in the following? Is there an acceptable design guideline to implement WS Notification Messaging in java? My scenario is the following: a web service client makes a web service call to a web service. 
After that, the web service should be able to send asynchronous notifications to the web client (as a result of the first web method call). What approach should be used?

Answer (score 1):

JAX-WS supports asynchronous web services and provides support for both a callback and polling model. The former model might be what you're looking for.

#### See also:

- [Asynchronous Web Service Invocation with JAX-WS 2.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/19/asynchronous-jax-ws-web-services.html)
- [Invoking JAX-WS Web services asynchronously](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxwsclientasync.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. These suggestions can be useful.
My intention is to send an one-way request to a web serice (as a subscription) and then get notifications at random intervals. Polling is good, but I will not get the notifications immediatelly. I was thinking to run a listening thread on a client and send a url to the web service to send the results/notifications to that url. The url would be send through SOAP header. Is there a way to access the SOAP headers in jax-ws? I want to access them in the result from the client in the result send by the service.
Thanks!

Comment: A correction. I want to access the headers both from the service and the client